# Is an answer automatically selected if the asker is gone?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

A question is asked, many answer are given to the person asking, but he won't accept one because he simply won't come again on SO.

Does an answer is automatically selected and rewarded or the work put in an answer is only rewarded if and only if the OP selected one of the answer given ?

Comment: Out of the reputation gained from an answer, only 15 rep comes from acceptance (which depends on OP), but majority of the rep comes from upvotes which you receive for that answer, and bounties, if anyone decides that the answer deserves more than what it got.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, votes will determine the best answer over time. An answer will never be marked automatically if the user never returns.

Comment: Imagining that nobody vote on the answers given, what will happen in this case ?

Comment: Nothing, it will gather dust.

Comment: @Fortune: There are plenty feature-requests to allow forcing acceptance / correcting acceptant and the like. Just search for them, they were and will always be declined.